# removing dialog-fragment when activity is paused

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have universal AsyncTask, that adds DialogFragment to currentActivity when starts and removes it when it's done. It works good, but when my activity is in background when task finishes, it crashes with error "can't do this after onSaveInstance", because it tries to remove fragment when the activity is paused. 
What can i do to remove the fragment after resuming my activity, and how can i check that i can't do it now, because activity is paused?

I use this in several different activities, so i don't want to add field "isActive" based on onPause/onResume events, because i would have to override them in every activity.  In sample below WaitingPopupFragment is my class that add Dialog Fragment to activity, and removes it in "hide".

```
public abstract class AsyncTaskWithWaiterAndException<Param,Progress,Result> extends 
AsyncTaskWithExceptionHandler<Param,Progress,Result>
{
    protected FragmentActivity parent;

    public AsyncTaskWithWaiterAndException(FragmentActivity parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        WaitingPopupFragment.Show(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) 
    {
        WaitingPopupFragment.Hide();
    }




}
```